# Vector notation in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, vector

I'm trying to use the `siunitx` package to format a number which is a vector (using `\hat{x}` to represent a vector in the x direction).  Using `\hat{x}` leads to complaints about invalid tokens.

After seeing [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37994/22887), I tried including

```
\sisetup{input-symbols=\hatx\haty}

\protected\def\hatx{\ensuremath{\hat{x}}}
\protected\def\haty{\ensuremath{\hat{y}}}
```

to my preamble.  Then, I get `siunitx error: "misplaced-sign-token" Misplaced sign token '+'.`

For completeness, here's what I am trying now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{input-symbols=\hatx\haty}

\protected\def\hatx{\ensuremath{\hat{x}}}
\protected\def\haty{\ensuremath{\hat{y}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = \SI{-3.24e-20\hatx + 4.56e-18\haty}{\newton}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how I can get this kind of thing to work properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to simply use:

```
\vec{F} = (\num{-3.24e-20}\hatx + \num{4.56e-18}\haty) \,\si{\newton}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\protected\def\hatx{\ensuremath{\hat{x}}}
\protected\def\haty{\ensuremath{\hat{y}}}

\begin{document}
\SI{1234}{\newton}

\num{1234}\,\si{\newton}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{F} = (\num{-3.24e-20}\hatx + \num{4.56e-18}\haty) \,\si{\newton}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add the parentheses around the vector, or the expression is mathematically different from what it should mean.

Comment: @egreg: Yep. I had it originally but was experimenting to see how it looked without the parenthesis and copied the wrong one here.  Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. But this eliminates the spacing that is normally provided by `siunitx`, I think?

Comment: @Tyler: Can you elaborate on which spacing you are referring to. AFAIK, The `\SI` macro is just a short form for of using `\num` for the number and `\si` for the units, both of which are part of the `siunitx` pacakge.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/G1dfZ.png).  The first is with `\SI{1234}{\newton}`.  The second is with `\num{1234}\si{\newton}`.

Comment: @Tyler: Sorry for missing that the first time. Have corrected it to include that spacing.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you try the `mandi` package? It is designed to handle this very thing. Furthermore, it is designed so that the user need never worry about a physical quantity's units because they are all baked into the package. For example, you can say `\force{5}` and get

[image: force magnitude]

You can also say `\force{\mivector{2,4,-5}}` and get the expected result

[image: force vector]

although it won't be formatted as in your example above. `mandi` was begun before `siunitx` came into existence and thus relies on the `SIunits` package for defining unit names, but in the next major release `mandi` will be independent of both `SIunits` and `siunitx` while, hopefully, not preventing use of the latter.

Disclaimer: I am the author of `mandi`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this package, but reading through the documentation, it looks very interesting.  For now, I would prefer to keep using the vector notation from above, but your package does allow for a more readable source file.